# Laravel 5.8 Eloquent check if record exists

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Trying to check if `record` exists in `Purchase` class.

When returning `$checker` it returns me `null` however when I use it inside `if else` it gives me `Has data`.

Here's my code:

```php
$checker = Purchase::select('id')->where('id',$request->itemid)->get();
if ($checker === null){
    echo "None data";
} else {
    echo "Has data";
}
```

Comment: If it equals null that would be the case for no record right? You reversed the if/else

Comment: @onlineThomas I edited my post, kindly recheck.

Comment: Use `->first()` instead of `->get()`

Comment: It doesn't echo anything now @AyazShah

Comment: @kwestionable are you forgetting the semi color after it ?

Comment: After `->first()`? No @AyazShah

Comment: @kwestionable yes you must add `;` after it so it will be `->first();`

Comment: `->get()` should not return null. It should return a collection, which might be empty.

Comment: @AyazShah yep I did, still nothing.

Comment: @apokryfos I don't know the term, but it does return  `[ ]`

Comment: @kwestionable try this `Purchase::where('id',$request->itemid)->first();`

Comment: @kwestionable it would be handy to see more code, where is itemid coming from? if you dd($request->itemid); what do you get?

Comment: you can use the code provided in the answer section

Comment: It should return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections) if you're getting a `[ ]` that's probably just an artefact of what you're using to see the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel's Query Builder has various aggregate methods, one of which is the `exists()` method wherein you can check if a record exists or not.

```
//returns true or false
$checker = Purchase::select('id')->where('id',$request->itemid)->exists();
```

Here's the documentation link for reference:

1. [From Laravel 5.6 to 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#aggregates)
2. [Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist)

Answer (score 2):

Or a ternary:

```
echo (Purchase::select('id')->where('id',$request->itemid)->exists()) ? "Has Data" : "No Data";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if ($checker ->first()) { } 
if (!$checker ->isEmpty()) { }
if ($checker ->count()) { }
if (count($checker )) { }
if ($checker ->isNotEmpty()) { }
```

You can try any one of these to check and you will get your desired output.

Comment: Using count(), I get an error "Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

Comment: This is bad syntax: if ($checker ->isNotEmpty()) { }
Use if(!empty($checker) { } instead

Answer (score 1):

To determine if any records exist that match your query's constraints, you may use the exists and doesntExist methods. It will return `true` or `false`:

```
$checker = Purchase::where('id',$request->itemid)->exists();

if ($checker){
    echo "Has data";
} else {
    echo "None data";
}
```

Or, you may do the reverse:

```
$checker = Purchase::where('id',$request->itemid)->doesntExist();

if ($checker){
    echo "None data";
} else {
    echo "Has data";
}
```

See the Laravel Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/queries#where-exists-clauses

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
if (isset(Purchase::select("id")->find($request->itemid)->id))
```